# How can I pass a controller's scope property to a custom directive?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox

**Basic Setup:**

I have a modal form that has a custom directive (child element) inside of it. The custom directive is a button. The modal consists of an input checkbox as well.

**The End Goal:**

Whenever the checkbox is 'checked', the custom directive/button element should be enabled. If the checkbox is 'unchecked', the custom directive/button should be disabled.

**What I have so far AKA my thought process:**

In the 'modalController' I put an ng-model on the checkbox input to dynamically change the value of a variable (isChecked). When the input is checked it sets the $scope.isChecked value to true, when it's unchecked, $scope.isChecked is false.

In order to disable the button I would pass the value of 'isChecked' from the modalController to the custom directive where its value can be put in the ng-checked expression on the button located inside the directive template (see-below).

**The Problem**

When I try this solution, the console log shows an error saying "inputCheck is not defined". This happens as soon as the page loads, so the console log gets printed before the user can even click the checkbox.  Any ideas on how to make this work?

Modal html:

```
  <div ng-controller= "modalController">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="isChecked">
    <button-directive inputCheck="isChecked"></button-directive>
  </div>
```

ButtonDirective.js:

```
angular.module('starter').directive('buttonDirective', function ($uibModal) {
    return {
        restrict: "EA",
        templateUrl: "app/directives/button-directive.html",
        scope: {
          inputCheck: "@"    
        },
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) { 
                  console.log(inputCheck);
         }]
     };
});
```

button-directive.html:

```
<button ng-checked="inputCheck">
```

Comment: Does $scope.inputCheck work?

Comment: no it just says it's undefined

Comment: May I please understand why the downvote?

Comment: That wasn't me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working the way you did.

You were passing attribute wrong, angularjs have a bad thing IMO that is when you are passing values to a directive like that inputCheck, you must write it different with hiphen so it needs to be `input-check`

```
<button-directive input-check="isChecked"></button-directive>
```

And your scope declaration must use equal sign

```
scope: {
  inputCheck: "="    
},
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/5jlHaE0fvhoDPi2h8XGq?p=preview

Comment: @Kode_12 could you make a jsfiddle of it? or a plunker

Comment: I so wish, I cannot share my code for client NDA reasons

Comment: @Kode_12 I see.

Comment: WOW, it's always the small mistakes that are so easy to overlook! Thank you it works as expected now :)

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong. $scope variable is different from that directive scope declaration.

Every child, including directives, are within $scope scope, get it?

So your directive declaration don't need that scope, remove it.

```
angular.module('starter').directive('buttonDirective', function ($uibModal) {
    return {
        restrict: "EA",
        templateUrl: "app/directives/button-directive.html"
     };
});
```

And your modal, no need to pass your inputCheck attribute.

```
 <div ng-controller= "modalController">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="isChecked">
    <button-directive></button-directive>
  </div>
```

Then your directive html becomes

```
<button ng-checked="isChecked">
```

See this

https://plnkr.co/edit/icaufi3LJxTnbTOkmxdb

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Even though it's a child element, the custom directive is automatically an isolate scope. Would I have to declare 'scope : true'?

Comment: @Kode_12 no you don't. Let's try to make your way work. I will give another answer.

Comment: @Kode_12 see the plunker I posted in this answer

Comment: this looks good. I just don't know why this isn't working in my code. Let me try replicating this, and i'll update you in a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

You should do following changes:

```
<button-directive input-check="isChecked"></button-directive>

scope: {
  inputCheck: "="    
}

<button ng-disabled="inputCheck">
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use:

```
return {
   scope: { varName: '='
},
controller: function($scope){
    console.log($scope.varName);   // anything from RETURN -> SCOPE gets automatically inserted into $scope
}
```